# Openfire : unable to converse with some external servers

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm running Openfire 3.9.3 with Debian Wheezy. When I use it, it works well with accounts registred on the server. I have a problem with accounts on others servers.

I tried to create an account on im.6x8.org and im.apinc.org. It works well. Then I tried with an account on jappix.com and I have the following problems :

- I can't see my account status from the jappix server and reciprocally
- I can send messages from the jappix account and my local account receive it
- When I send messages from my local account to jappix, it didn't work. In some clients, I have the error "remote-server-not-found".

When I go to the server sessions in openfire console, I see that jappix has only an incoming connection but im.apinc.org have the both.

In the warn logs, I found this :

```
2014.12.05 08:12:52 org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.ServerDialback - ServerDialback: OS - Ignoring unexpected answer in validation from: jappix.com id: 7cf4a0dc-cad9-470a-80dc-d431dba5cfd1 for domain: xmpp.myserver.org answer:<stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><bidi xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:bidi"/><dialback xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:dialback"><errors/></dialback><sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:2"><optional/></sm><sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"><optional/></sm><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression></stream:features>
2014.12.05 08:12:52 org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.ServerDialback - ServerDialback: OS - Ignoring unexpected answer in validation from: jappix.com id: 7cf4a0dc-cad9-470a-80dc-d431dba5cfd1 for domain: xmpp.myserver.org answer:<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><policy-violation xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams">TLS encryption is mandatory but wasn't used</text></stream:error>
```

More logs here : http://pastebin.com/6nV0ytA8

In the firewall, I have the ports 5222, 5223, 5269, 7777, 5229, 7070 and 7443 open in tcp.

I spend a lot of time trying to resolve this but I found nothing and I have no more idea. Someone have an idea ?

Thanks by advance.

Regards,

---

Edit :

I just saw that jappix was with secure connection and not the others. If I force it, I have the same problem. I try to change the certificate with a valid one but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

From the original logs, I see `TLS encryption is mandatory but wasn't used`- so apparently jappix.com needs you to support encrypted S2S connections.

btw, you can test your XMPP server (and others) via https://xmpp.net/

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Yes, I found later that jappix wasn't working because it was forcing me to use s2s encryption and the others don't. After some search, I found that it is a know bug in openfire. So I juste installed ejabberd and it works fine